Problems with vncserver and/or vncviewer (black screen) - SuSE linux
I want to connect to my office PC from my home PC via VNC. I ssh'd to my office PC with ssh keys and start a server: "vncserver :2 -SecurityTypes=none". Then logout and start the viewer on my home PC: "vncviewer -via 'jump host' 'server PC' :2". The viewer opens a window and tells me that I'm connected. But..... The screen is black!! Only the very first time it worked. Now nothing happens, the screen stays black.
Is this a DISPLAY error? Or what do you guess. I read a lot about this problem, but nothing seems to help.

I killed the vncserver manually and/or deleted the /tmp/.X0 or any other file of the same kind. Using "ps aux | grep vnc" shows nothing. Surprisingly, after I deleted the vnc program, I got using "echo $DISPLAY" the answer: "localhost:10.0". Why? I think the normal display number is 0.

I want to add some new observations. I CAN start the VNC viewer if I only use the twm displaymanager in the .xstartup file on the server site. If I use startkde instead it gives me a "Call to lnusertemp failed (temporary directories full?). Check your installation." and the screen is black. I checked /var/tmp and /tmp, but there is enough space . What to do?.
How do I know if Wayland is running or not?

What do you by Only the very first time it worked? So if you kill the vncserver and start it again, does it work when you connect to it "for the first time"?

Are you trying to connect to the running x/wayland session?
